# Getting User attributes from MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, oracle, webforms

I am using `Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider` MembershipProvider for my ASP.NET application. My login form has username, password and email address.

After logging in, I can access the user name with `User.Identity.Name`.

1. How can I retrieve email address? I cannot find this in User object.
2. How can I alter the have two different types of users (Those with write access and those with read access).
3. I need to create another tables with the userid as foreign key. How can I retrieve that so that I can enter in other tables as foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user object using either:

```
[C#]
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser("username");
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUserNameByEmail("email");
```

1. This method returns a `MembershipUser` object. With this object you can retrieve email and other properties.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by different types of users but you can user Roles.
3. You can use `ProviderUserKey` property of `MembershipUser` to get UserId as `System.Guid`

Answer (score 0):

The Principal set on the thread after authentication is generic in nature and does not contain these details. One approach would be to extend the IPrincipal and IIdentity interfaces by adding the new properties and set them during the authentication phase. But this requires tinkering with the authentication\authorization mechanism, which is not ideal approach.
Another approach can be to create a custom User Class in your problem domain and load it's data when the user gets authenticated. This User class can contain any desired properties and and any related entities. This would be custom code and would not use the ASP.Net security infrastructure.